# Fastest way for python requests + mysql + multiprocessing

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-requests, multiprocessing

I need to run a script which use requests and send data to mysql database

right now I'm using multiprocessing.dummy and ThreadPool. Sample code:

```
pool = ThreadPool(10)

def run(l):
    #few lines of code, there is no need to paste everything

    #get last id from mysql table
    find_id = "SELECT * FROM Items ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1"
    mycursor.execute(find_id)

    #I'm making request and then need to send data to mysql db
    data = requests.get(...).text
    ...
    mydb.commit()


results = pool.map(run, urls)
```

Everything would be great, but I feel script is not as fast as it should be with 10 threads (it's almost as slow as one thread). I checked process id with:

```
os.getpid()
```

and every thread has the same id. Anyway, the biggest problem is after some time, maybe 10-20 minutes, script gets slower and slower until one thread stop in the middle of function and everything stops forever.

I also tried multiprocessing.Process with queues but it didn't work as I want. Every thread/process used the same last row from mysql table (check my find_id variable in code above) and processes/threads were connecting to the database at the same time as causing it to lock...

In past I've used multiprocessing for simple requests and everything worked perfectly even for more threads, so I guess there is a problem with python multiprocessing and mysql commits at the same time.

QUESTION:

Is there any effective way that could work for me? Requests + mysql commits and everything run with few workers/threads/processes at the same time.

Comment: I'd suggest profiling the code to find out where it's spending time.  e.g. is it the `SELECT` query taking time, the remote server taking time to come back with answer, writing data into the database, or something else?